# Active Record query through relationship to find Record where none of its relationships have true for a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

Rails 6.0 with Postrgres

I have got a relational model where an  Employee `has_many` Jobs and every job has a boolean value for `active`.

If every Job that an Employee has is `active: false` than that employee is no longer employed. So I want to do a query for employees where every job they have has `active: false` to figure out which employees are no longer employed.

I tried something like

```rb
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  scope :terminated, -> { 
    includes(:jobs).
      where.not(jobs: {
        active: true,
      })
  }
```

but this is finding employees where they have **any** job where `active` is not `true`. I want to find employees where **every** job has `active` `false`. Can AR do this natively?

Comment: what database are you using? Postgres, MySQL..?

Comment: @Mshka my bad. Question updated to reflect that this is Postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to join the jobs table twice and use an alias:

```
SELECT "employees".* FROM "employees" 
INNER JOIN "jobs" 
  ON "jobs"."employee_id" = "employees"."id" 
INNER JOIN "jobs" "inactive_jobs" 
  ON "inactive_jobs"."employee_id" = "employees"."id" 
  AND "inactive_jobs"."active" = 0 
GROUP BY "employees"."id" 
HAVING COUNT("jobs"."id") = COUNT("inactive_jobs"."id") LIMIT ?
```

ActiveRecord doesn't really have a straight forwards way of doing joins with aliases but with some Arel trickery you can make it happen.

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :jobs
  
  def self.terminated
    jobs = Job.arel_table
    # Needed to generate a join with an alias
    inactive_jobs = Job.arel_table.alias('inactive_jobs')
    # joins all the jobs
    joins(
      :jobs
    )
    # joins jobs where active: false
    .joins(
      self.arel_table.join(
          inactive_jobs,
          Arel::Nodes::InnerJoin
        ).on(
          inactive_jobs[:employee_id].eq(self.arel_table[:id])
            .and(inactive_jobs[:active].eq(false))
        ).join_sources
    )
    # groups on employee id
    .group(:id)
    # Set a condition on the group that the jobs must equal the number of inactive jobs
    .having(jobs[:id].count.eq(inactive_jobs[:id].count))
  end
end
```

If you add a counter-cache you can cheat and remove the second join:

```
class Job
  belongs_to :employee, counter_cache: true
end

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :jobs

  def self.terminated
    joins(:jobs)
      .where(jobs: { active: false })
      .group(:id)
      .having(arel_table[:jobs_count].eq(Job.arel_table[Arel.star].count)) 
  end
end
```

Here you're comparing the cached value against the number of join rows.

Comment: I was  scared the best answer would be as long as the first one! But this does get it done and the second iteration is very clever. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `scope` for this type of queries because if there are no matching records, the `scope` returns all the records for that Model.
You can write a class method for this:

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :jobs

  def self.terminated
    preload(:jobs)
      .reject { |employee| employee.jobs.where(active: true).present? }
  end
end
```

Comment: This is extremely unperformant but it would work as a last case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
   has_one :jobs
   scope :terminated, ->{ joins(:jobs).merge(Job.inactive) }
end

class Job < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :employee
  scope :inactive, -> { where(active: false) }
end
```

Employee.terminated should return all employees who only have jobs for which active is false.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I still receive employees who have some jobs with active true in the terminated scope

Comment: @Andrew Can you describe the association you used between Employee and Job. I can't understand why this wouldn't work unless you have a more complex association than what I described above.
Maybe you can also show us the result of  Employee.terminated.to_sql
Can you confirm the active column is a boolean right?

Comment: This does not work since an inner join will return records if they have at least one match in the join table.

Comment: Ah exact, it would work if one employee has only one job :D